# Why doesnt switching between templates work in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to switch between two templates using render in the same function. It worked with one project, but not with this one. I'm going mental. It's about a math quiz, where you can choose between level 1 and level 3. after POST it should render a new html where i can make the layout, but it simply doesnt switch to layout.html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title">Math Quiz</p>
    <div class="box">

        <button type="submit" onclick="lvl(1)">Level 1</button><br><br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="lvl(2)">Level 2</button><br><br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="lvl(3)">Level 3</button>
        <script>
            function lvl(num) {
                fetch("",{
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' // Include the CSRF token in the headers
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "num": num
                    })
                })
            };
        </script>
            

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title">Math Quiz2</p>
    <div class="box">
        <form method="POST">
            <p>{{ quiz }}</p>
        </form>
            

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import random

# Create your views here.
def appView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body_data = json.loads(body_unicode)
        num = body_data.get('num')
        return _quiz(request,num)
    return render(request,"index.html")

def _quiz(request,lvl=1):
    operation = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
    string = str(random.randint(0,100)) +" "+ str(operation[random.randint(0,3)]) + " " + str(random.randint(1,10*lvl))
    result = eval(string)
    string += " = "
    return render(request, "layout.html", {"string": string, "result": result})
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch() is only downloading http response as data but it does not add html to DOM and does not display it in the browser.
But you could simply encode the level in the url in a href tag that is via urls.py translated to the view.

```
href={% url 'my-view-name' level=1 %}
```

in urls.py add

```
path("my_path/<int>:level", views.my_view, "my-view-name")
```

view:

```
def appView(request, level):
  ....
```